# How to use ethers.js keccak256 along with a salt phrase so that it's compatible with Solidity keccak256 function?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, keccak

I have a Solidity 0.4.26 smart contract. I'm using a commit-reveal pattern to hide to first user's commitment move.

I have a helper contract Hasher that hashes the user's commitment with a hash() function:

```
contract Hasher{
    /** @dev Give the commitement. Must only be called locally.
     *  @param _c The move.
     *  @param _salt The salt to increase entropy.
     */
    function hash(uint8 _c, uint256 _salt) constant returns(bytes32) {
        return keccak256(_c,_salt);
    }
}
```

The Solidity 0.4.26 implementation of a native keccak256 function allows 2 arguments: a message and a salt phrase.

For some reason, I cannot find an equivalent of that function in any JS-based library.

I'm ideally looking to code a Javascript keccak256 function that would be compatible with the Solidity's 0.4.26 keccak256 in order to later decrypt the commitment move with the salt:

```
require(keccak256(_c1,_salt)==c1Hash); // Verify the value is the commited one.
```

Please give me any advice on how I can achieve that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the equivalent hashing in JavaScript, you have to [`encodePacked`](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-solidityPack) the values `_c` and `_salt` before hashing. In ethers there is a helper method [`solidityKeccak256`](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-solidityKeccak256) which does exactly what you are looking for.

```js
const _c = 5;
const _salt = 10;
const hash = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['uint8', 'uint256'], [_c, _salt]);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!